# when using boto3 how to create an aws instance with a custom root volume size

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

When creating an instance in [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com) the volume root size defaults to 8GB, I am trying to create an instance using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/) but with a different default size, for example 300GB, I am currently trying  something like this without success:

```
block_device_mappings = []


block_device_mappings.append({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    'Ebs': {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        'VolumeSize': 300,                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        'DeleteOnTermination': True,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        'VolumeType': 'gp2'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what is happening is that you're using an AMI that uses `/dev/xvda` instead of `/dev/sda1` for its root volume.

AMIs these days support one of two types of virtualization, paravirtual (PV) or hardware virtualized (HVM), and PV images support `/dev/sda1` for the root device name, whereas HVM images can specify either `dev/xvda` or `/dev/sda1` (more from [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html)).

You can add in an image check to determine what the AMI you're using sets its root volume to, and then use that information for your calls to `create_images`.

Here's a code snippet that makes a call out to `describe_images`, retrieves information about its `RootDeviceName`, and then uses that to configure the block device mapping.

```
import boto3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = boto3.client('ec2')

    # This grabs the Debian Jessie 8.6 image (us-east-1 region)
    image_id = 'ami-49e5cb5e'

    response = client.describe_images(ImageIds=[image_id])

    device_name = response['Images'][0]['RootDeviceName']
    print(device_name)

    block_device_mappings = []

    block_device_mappings.append({
        'DeviceName': device_name,
        'Ebs': {
        'VolumeSize': 300,
        'DeleteOnTermination': True,
        'VolumeType': 'gp2'
        }
    })

    # Whatever you need to create the instances
```

For reference, the call to `describe_images` returns a `dict` that looks like this:

```
{u'Images': [{u'Architecture': 'x86_64',
   u'BlockDeviceMappings': [{u'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
     u'Ebs': {u'DeleteOnTermination': True,
      u'Encrypted': False,
      u'SnapshotId': 'snap-0ddda62ff076afbc8',
      u'VolumeSize': 8,
      u'VolumeType': 'gp2'}}],
   u'CreationDate': '2016-11-13T14:03:45.000Z',
   u'Description': 'Debian jessie amd64',
   u'EnaSupport': True,
   u'Hypervisor': 'xen',
   u'ImageId': 'ami-49e5cb5e',
   u'ImageLocation': '379101102735/debian-jessie-amd64-hvm-2016-11-13-1356-ebs',
   u'ImageType': 'machine',
   u'Name': 'debian-jessie-amd64-hvm-2016-11-13-1356-ebs',
   u'OwnerId': '379101102735',
   u'Public': True,
   u'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
   u'RootDeviceType': 'ebs',
   u'SriovNetSupport': 'simple',
   u'State': 'available',
   u'VirtualizationType': 'hvm'}],
 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
   'date': 'Mon, 19 Dec 2016 14:03:36 GMT',
   'server': 'AmazonEC2',
   'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
   'vary': 'Accept-Encoding'},
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'RequestId': '85a22932-7014-4202-92de-4b5ee6b7f73b',
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```